# No contacts showing in list in messages

Tags: contacts

I have just purchased a Galaxy s4 mini and I can see all my contacts in the contacts list but when I want to send a message and add a recipient the contact list is empty. How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you see on the contacts list? Is there `No results found`, or just an empty box?

Comment: How are you adding a contact? Typing  text in the `Enter recipient` or clicking the contacts button to its right?

Answer (score 0):

you may try any custom contacts/messaging app.
if you like you could try [contacts +](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.contapps.android&hl=en)
, which can also be used for texting.